# Convert to for of loop for standard for loop?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert this standard for loop to es6 for of loop.  I tried to convert it from the original :

```
   let formdata = document.forms[0].elements;  //let in place of var
   let numelems = formdata.length;
 for (let i = 0; i < numelems; i++){   // for of replaces for (let i = 0;i<numelems;i++){
                if (formdata[i].type == 'text' && formdata[i].value === ''){
                    msg += "<br>please enter your " + formdata[i].name;
                    checker = false;
                }
```

But it broke the page validation.
Here is the code I tried:

```
for (let i of numelems){   // for of replaces for (let i = 0;i<numelems;i++){
                if (formdata[i].type == 'text' && formdata[i].value === ''){
                    msg += "<br>please enter your " + formdata[i].name;
                    checker = false;
                }
```

Where did my code go wrong?

Comment: What is `numelems`?  The name suggests it is a number, so in theory your upper code should work and the lower part wouldn't.  You need to iterate over an array.  I would normally also phrase it as `for(const i of arr)` so you're not tempted to try to mutate keys.

Comment: `for..of` will work for array

Comment: `for..of` will give you *values*, not keys. You seem to be using it as if a `for..in`.

Comment: numelems is an array for the elements in the form.  I added the declarations up top just now

Comment: *let numelems = formdata.length;* how it can be an array?

Comment: `for(let data of formdata) { /* data is now the same as formdata[i] */}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `ES6` syntax of for-loop return every object of formdata in loop. So we dont't need to access element by index.  We can directly access its property like shown in code below.

```
for (let data of formdata) {

     if (data.type == 'text' && data.value === '') {

             msg += "<br>please enter your " + data.name;

             checker = false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    for (let data of formdata ) {  
       if (data.type == 'text' && data.value === ''){
           msg += "<br>please enter your " + data.name;
           checker = false;
        }
    }
```